# How to handle timeout with Perl module HTTP::Async?

Tags: perl, http, asynchronous, timeout

I know how to handle `timeout` on `HTTP::Request` operations when `LWP::UserAgent` is used, but as I need to use `HTTP::Async` module instead of the Perl module `LWP::UserAgent`, I am looking for alternative solution(s) to set timeout for async http request(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you *read* the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aAsync)?

To set the default timeout for requests:

```
# When creating the object:
my $async = HTTP::Async->new( timeout => 300 ); # 5 minutes
# Changing it later:
$async->timeout(600); # 10 minutes
```

To change the timeout for a single request:

```
$async->add_with_opts( $request, { timeout => 600 } ); # 10 minutes
```

**Update**: It seems there's [a bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=33071) and the `timeout` attribute doesn't actually work.

Comment: Has to be a timeout an positive integer number, or can that be with Time::HiRes also any positive decimal number?

Comment: HTTP::Async uses Time::HiRes, so it should work with fractional seconds.  I'm not sure why you'd need to set a timeout with subsecond precision, though.

Comment: Most examples I found online set their **timeout** to `max_request_time` option, not using `timeout` option at all. Why? What is then `timeout option` for? I am not sure why there are two settings: `max_request_time` and `timeout`.

Comment: The docs fail to explain this, but from looking at the source, a request aborts if no data has been received for `timeout` seconds or `max_request_time` seconds after the request was sent, whichever comes first.  I.E., `timeout` resets every time data is received, but `max_request_time` doesn't.